# how can i get number from this string by java?

Tags: java, string

216 Kleopatra is visible in the dawn sky, rising at 23:11 (KST) and reaching an altitude of 52° above the south-eastern horizon before fading from view as dawn breaks around 03:51.

from this string
i want to get the array of numbers like [216, 23, 11, 52, 3, 51]

how can i get it?

Comment: You could do it using `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Comment: Can we see what and all you tried for this? Please share the minimum code for what you have tried, otherwise the better question will be https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use split("\D+") with regex

https://www.onlinegdb.com/FCFoH2gNS

here is the code i made

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        String text ="216 Kleopatra is visible in the dawn sky, rising at 23:11 (KST) and reaching an altitude of 52 \u00B0 above the south-eastern horizon before fading from view as dawn breaks around 03:51.";
         System.out.println(text);
        String[] textarr= text.split("\\D+");
        for(int i = 0 ; i<textarr.length;i++){
                System.out.println(textarr[i]+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```